# Docker says file doesn't exist but it appears in docker shell

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm been bashing my head against the wall for hours trying to figure this out. I'm getting an `You have $NVM_DIR set to "/usr/local/nvm", but that directory does not exist` error from docker, but when I `docker exec -it <container> bash` into the container, I can see `/usr/local/nvm` clear as day.

I've got my Dockerfile below, as well as the docker-compose.yml and the output from the `docker compose build` step.

**Dockerfile** (up until error)

```
FROM rust:1.63 as runner

# Install Node and NPM with NVM
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
ENV NODE_VERSION v18.9.0
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm use --delete-prefix $NODE_VERSION"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'
    image: library/rustapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      ROCKET_ADDRESS: '0.0.0.0'
      PORT: 8001
      ENVIRONMENT: STAGING
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/frontend/:/home/app/frontend
```

**Output of `docker compose build`**

```
[+] Building 0.3s (6/12)                                                                                                                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.dev                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/rust:1.63                                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR FROM docker.io/library/rusty-builder:latest                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/rusty-builder:latest                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => CACHED [runner 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/rust:1.63                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [runner 2/8] RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash                                                             0.2s
------
 > FROM docker.io/library/rusty-builder:latest:
------
------
 > [runner 2/8] RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash:
#0 0.140   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#0 0.140                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15037  100 15037    0     0   183k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  183k
#0 0.227 You have $NVM_DIR set to "/usr/local/nvm", but that directory does not exist. Check your profile files and environment.
------
failed to solve: failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

Comment: Version managers like `nvm` don't really work well in Docker.  It's unclear why you're trying to build a Javascript application on top of a Rust image base; can you build your image `FROM node:18.9` (maybe as part of a multi-stage build)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I've got a rust backend and react frontend and I'm working on building out auto-reload on both for developer experience. I don't know of a way of doing that with one dockerfile without having both sets of build tooling in the same image, and starting with rust has shown to be easier than starting with node. I'm probably just going to build a combined image with both later

Comment: you just need to create the folder. add `RUN mkdir /usr/local/nvm` before running the install script

Comment: removing the line `ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm` also works and then you don't have to create the path, it will be installed at /root/.nvm (it's in a container so it shouldn't matter)